# NGINX Can not resolve index.html - Cloudflare SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, cloudflare

I've attempted to install an SSL cert with nginx. 
I followed their steps yet my index.html page is not rendering.

I have tried many alterations to the config, but nothing seems to work.
The issue seems to be in the config.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com_key.pem;
    server_name example.com

    root /var/www/landing;
    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

Comment: What error do you get? Anything in the nginx logs?

Comment: I get no errors in the logs. When I load the site, cloudflare simply tells me that the site is down and can not resolve the host.